# Saving jQuery UI Sortable order in Wordpress Backend

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, jquery-ui

I try to change the order of the taxonomy terms per post basis in Wordpress. On EDIT POST page, I've created a metabox containing custom taxonomy terms and managed to make them sortable via Jquery.

This is my list on **Wordpress backend**:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        // Make the term list sortable
        jQuery("#the-terms").sortable({
                items: ".item",
                placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
                tolerance: "pointer",
                distance: 1,
                forcePlaceholderSize: true,
                helper: "clone",
                cursor: "move",
        });
        // Save the order using ajax
        jQuery("#save_term_order").on("click", function () {
                var postID = $("#post_ID").val();
                jQuery.post(ajaxurl, {
                        action: "save_term_order",
                        cache: false,
                        post_id: postID,
                        order: jQuery("#the-terms").sortable("toArray").toString(),
                        success: ajax_response(),
                });
                return false;
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="inside">
    <ul id="the-terms" class="ui-sortable">
        <li class="item" id="term-816">Item 1</li>
        <li class="item" id="term-895">Item 2</li>
        <li class="item" id="term-1034">Item 3</li>
    </ul><a href="javascript: void(0); return false;" id="save_term_order" class="button-primary">Update Order</a>
</div>
```

This works so far. But when I try to save the order of taxonomy terms with click on the button, it throws:

```
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ajax_response
    (anonymous function) (post.php:249)
    dispatch (load-scripts.php:2:43096)
[Error] SyntaxError: Return statements are only valid inside functions.
    (anonymous function) (post.php:1)
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'o.stack.indexOf')
    (anonymous function) (common.min.js:2:131350)
    each (load-scripts.php:2:2981)
    onError (common.min.js:2:131320)
    dispatch (load-scripts.php:2:43096)
```

**My question:**

I am completely new to Jquery and PHP development. What should I do to save the terms order to the database on button click?

**EDIT: I am using this ajax function to save the order as a custom field:**

```
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_save_term_order', 'term_order_save' );
function term_order_save () {
  global $wpdb;
  $wpdb->flush ();
  $item_id = $_POST['post_id'];
  $meta_key = '_term_order';

  $order = $_POST[ 'order' ];
  $str = str_replace ( "term-", "", $order );
  $int = str_replace ( "'", "", $str );

  update_post_meta ( $item_id, $meta_key, array ( 'term_order' => $int ) );

  $response = '<p>Term order updated</p>';
  echo $response;

  die(1);
}
```

It doesn't seem to update the custom fields.

Comment: The php line `$int = str_replace ( "'", "", $str );` makes no sense. Your string will not contain `'`, it would contain `,`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You helped a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I see is that there are a few things undefined:

- `ajaxurl`
- `ajax_response()`

Those will need to be defined before this script runs.

Here is an example that might help you.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  function getListOrder(tObj) {
    var list = $(tObj).sortable("toArray");
    return list.toString();
  }
  
  var ajaxUrl = "";
  
  // Make the term list sortable
  $("#the-terms").sortable({
    items: ".item",
    placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    distance: 1,
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move",
  });
  
  // Save the order using ajax
  $("#save_term_order").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var postID = $("#post_ID").val();
    var listOrder = getListOrder("#the-terms");
    console.log("List Order:", listOrder);
    $.post(ajaxUrl, {
      action: "save_term_order",
      cache: false,
      post_id: postID,
      order: listOrder,
      success: true
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="inside">
  <ul id="the-terms" class="ui-sortable">
    <li class="item" id="term-816">Item 1</li>
    <li class="item" id="term-895">Item 2</li>
    <li class="item" id="term-1034">Item 3</li>
  </ul><a href="javascript: void(0); return false;" id="save_term_order" class="button-primary">Update Order</a>
</div>
```

WordPress uses `jQuery()` but you can pass in a NameSPace to use for that code block. Using `jQuery(function($){})` will allow you to use `$("#the-terms")` for example.

I split the collection of the list into it's own function just to make it easier to call, it returns the String.

**Update**

For your PHP, consider the following.

Example Post:

```
{
  action: "save_term_order",
  cache: false,
  post_id: "3001",
  order: "term-816,term-1034,term-895"
}
```

If you want to add `8161034895` to your database, try this.

```
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_save_term_order', 'term_order_save' );
function term_order_save () {
  global $wpdb;
  $wpdb->flush ();
  $item_id = $_POST['post_id'];
  $meta_key = '_term_order';

  $int = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $_POST['order']);

  update_post_meta ( $item_id, $meta_key, array ( 'term_order' => $int ) );

  $response = '<p>Term order updated</p>';
  echo $response;

  die(0);
}
```

> The status 0 is used to terminate the program successfully.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It has eliminated the errors, which have been a headache for days. However, the terms do not seem to be ordered yet.

Comment: I am using this ajax function to save the order as a custom field:

 add_action ( 'wp_ajax_save_term_order', 'term_order_save' );
function term_order_save () {
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->flush ();
    $item_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    $meta_key = '_term_order';

    $order = $_POST[ 'order' ];
    $str = str_replace ( "term-", "", $order );
    $int = str_replace ( "'", "", $str );

    update_post_meta ( $item_id, $meta_key, array ( 'term_order' => $int ) );

    $response = '<p>Term order updated</p>';
    echo $response;

    die(1);
}

Comment: @bonsvr not sure what you mean by *terms do not seem to be ordered yet.* They will be in whatever order you drag and drop them and then hit the button. You should see the order in your Console and that is what is sent to Script. If the DB is different, then something is wrong in the DB Update Script.

Comment: sorry for the long code post. I've updated the question, adding my PHP code. Do you think there is a mismatch?